# Semantic UI Table responsive issues inside a Semantic UI modal

Tags: responsive, semantic-ui

I'd like, if there is a way, to make responsive in tablet view the situation in which you are given to design a *sementic-ui-table* with about 15 headers inside a *sementic-ui* modal, It behaves responsive in Desktop and mobile view. In tablet view, some of the headers are displayed out of the modal. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: I have fixed some of the punctuation, grammar and styling. Am still not sure whether the question makes sense, though.

Comment: You could try changing the css for the `.ui.modal .content` class to `overflow-x: scroll`